# r generate random binary outcome with given probability

Tags: r

I wish to generate random binary outcome with a given probability of 0.05.
So in average I should get a positive (1) and 19 negatives (0) every 20 draws.

How can I do that with R ?

I see how I can generate with a 0.5 probability:

```
sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
mean(sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T))
[1] 0.5034
```

But I would need a probability of 0.05.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a random generator for the binomial distribution whose purpose is exactly to generate such samples:

```
x <- rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.05)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a parameter `prob` in the `sample` function.

Your call would then be

```
sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T,prob=c(0.95,0.05))
```

Comment: Not `prob = c(0.95, 0.05)`? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to generate just a random sign (like my case!!) and you don't want the whole interval... you can use:

```
2*rbinom(n=1, size=1, prob=0.5)-1
```

This will generate +1 or -1 as output.

Note that `prob=0.5`, you will need to adjust it for your desired probability.